# I cannot boot if mdadm RAID1 array is in FSTAB

Tags: boot, mount, raid, fstab, mdadm

**Context:**

Due to a failed update from 20.04 to a 22.04, I decided to reinstall from zero the 22.04.
All things went fine, but I’m with an unbootable system if I left RAID entry at FSTAB.
I have a 2 disk RAID1 at sdc and sdd, that is clean and working perfectly when mounted, but at boot I enter in Emergency Mode, and can only resume boot capacity when nano /etc/fstab and comment /mnt/raid1 entry.

Here the **STEPS** that I followed, based in [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-raid-arrays-with-mdadm-on-ubuntu-18-04), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/658/linux-how-can-i-view-all-uuids-for-all-available-disks-on-my-system), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129497/difference-between-uuid-from-blkid-and-mdadm), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199628/raid-devices-are-mounted-with-different-uuid) and [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815253/is-it-safe-to-use-uuids-in-fstab-with-a-software-raid-mdadm):

```
$ sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sd[cd]1
mdadm: /dev/md0 has been started with 2 drives.

$ sudo mdadm --detail --scan --verbose
ARRAY /dev/md0 level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=1.2 name=desktopubuntu:0 UUID=feba8274:e93bd0e4:9a754d82:65c19cf8
   devices=/dev/sdc1,/dev/sdd1

$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sd[cd]1
/dev/sdc1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : feba8274:e93bd0e4:9a754d82:65c19cf8
           Name : desktopubuntu:0
  Creation Time : Sat Apr  2 19:42:37 2022
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 3906762928 sectors (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 1953381440 KiB (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906762880 sectors (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=48 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : e673bc23:383a992c:45571ac2:3b3e73d1

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Thu Sep  8 01:44:26 2022
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : 4df6a1a2 - correct
         Events : 7694

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdd1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : feba8274:e93bd0e4:9a754d82:65c19cf8
           Name : desktopubuntu:0
  Creation Time : Sat Apr  2 19:42:37 2022
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 3906762928 sectors (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 1953381440 KiB (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906762880 sectors (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=48 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 8491858d:9a1cf323:d579b65f:167bbe73

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Thu Sep  8 01:44:26 2022
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : ef01010d - correct
         Events : 7694

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

So, I did this:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/raid1
sudo mount /dev/md0 /mnt/raid1/
sudo chmod g+s /mnt/raid1
sudo chown -R marcelo:fileshareforall /mnt/raid1
```

At this point I can use it, write and read any file or folder.

Now, I proceeded with that:

```
$ sudo mdadm --detail --scan --verbose | sudo tee -a /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
ARRAY /dev/md0 level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=1.2 name=desktopubuntu:0 UUID=feba8274:e93bd0e4:9a754d82:65c19cf8
   devices=/dev/sdc1,/dev/sdd1
```

With that, I unmount the RAID partition and tested fstab with:

```
$ sudo mount -av
/                        : ignored
/boot/efi                : already mounted
/mnt/raid1               : successfully mounted
```

And:

```
$ lsblk -f NAME FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
loop0
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/bare/5
...
loop20
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/notepad-plus-plus/374
sda                                                                         
├─sda1
│    vfat   FAT32       B421-8498                              59,5M    38% /boot/efi
├─sda2
│                                                                           
├─sda3
│    ntfs         Win_SSD
│                       D280529F805289BD                                    
├─sda4
│    ntfs               149E0BCF9E0BA876                                    
├─sda5
│    ntfs               54306E95306E7DBC                                    
├─sda6
│    ntfs               749AEA539AEA1182                                    
└─sda7
     ext4   1.0         733b6c76-48d1-4d26-85bb-697075f27b0d                
sdb                                                                         
├─sdb1
│    ext4   1.0         0bd7c897-38c6-4d18-ad8c-4a3d1270cfe4  158,8G     8% /
├─sdb2
│    ntfs               FC8675048674C126                                    
└─sdb3
                                                                            
sdc                                                                         
└─sdc1
     linux_ 1.2   desktopubuntu:0
                        feba8274-e93b-d0e4-9a75-4d8265c19cf8                
  └─md0
     ext4   1.0         6f72b003-711e-47d7-8028-99b9d001ba99    1,6T     5% /mnt/raid1
sdd                                                                         
└─sdd1
     linux_ 1.2   desktopubuntu:0
                        feba8274-e93b-d0e4-9a75-4d8265c19cf8                
  └─md0
     ext4   1.0         6f72b003-711e-47d7-8028-99b9d001ba99    1,6T     5% /mnt/raid1
```

With all pieces in place, I did:

```
$: sudo update-initramfs -u
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-47-generic
```

Without any feedback, bash got back to $ blinking cursor. I‘m assuming this is the expected behavior.

I complete these steps now 5 times, and in every round I got a boot in Emergency Mode, and can only resume boot capacity when `nano /etc/fstab` and comment /mnt/raid1 entry.

Any directions? What I’m missing?
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the sixth time that I went through the same process above described, I tried only one thing different:
I manually deleted the previous mdadm.config

```
sudo rm /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

Before, I were only issuing the below command to recreate it with:

```
sudo mdadm --detail --scan --verbose | sudo tee -a /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

I can't see any difference at **mdadm.conf**, but now I'm able to boot normally without any Emergency Mode boot.

I can boot with live.usb and run a `sudo fsck -f /` with no errors...

I do not understand what happened - corruption of mdadm.conf?

Anyway, that's a fix...